# Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin issues

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

There are a few questions on this here, but I could not find a question to my answer.
I am new to Javascript etc, so please be patient.

I am trying to make a page with some input fields where people could add information e.g. Title, date, time etc. and it then gets added to the Android or iOS native calendar.

I dont think the installation steps are the greatest at https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin

Nevertheless, I believe I got the plugin installed, but how do I now get it working?

Here is some of the code:

```
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/Calendar.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            function createMyEvent(){
                var cal = new calendarPlugin();

                console.log("creating event");
                var title= "My Sample Appt";
                var location = "Los Angeles";
                var notes = "This is a sample note";
                var startDate = "2014-01-20 09:30:00";
                var endDate = "2014-01-20 12:30:00";
                var errCall = function(theerror) {
                    console.log("Error occurred - " + theerror);
                }
                var succCall = function(themessage) {
                    console.log("Success - " + themessage);
                }
                cal.createEvent(title,location,notes,startDate,endDate, succCall, errCall);
            }
        </script>
```

...
...

```
<div data-role="content">
<a data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="right" onclick="createMyEvent();">
        Add Event
      </a>

          <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
          </script>
</div>
```

Comment: you should read the usage section in the plugin's readme.md

Answer (score 1):

Add deviceready event. It should work.

**Note :** If you are using phonegap build then you dont need to include Calendar.js file. Phonegap build automatically adds it. All you need is to add follwoing in config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.calendar" />
```

Here is function to create event.

```
      function createMyEvent(){
            var cal = new calendarPlugin();

            console.log("creating event");
            var title= "My Sample Appt";
            var location = "Los Angeles";
            var notes = "This is a sample note";
            var startDate = "2014-01-20 09:30:00";
            var endDate = "2014-01-20 12:30:00";
            var errCall = function(theerror) {
                console.log("Error occurred - " + theerror);
            }
            var succCall = function(themessage) {
                console.log("Success - " + themessage);
            }
            cal.createEvent(title,location,notes,startDate,endDate, succCall, errCall);
        }
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", Calendar_Add, false);
```